# Summing a data-frame column based on list values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame df which the head looks like:

```
             total_cost  
date                                                                       
2006-03-04 -1465.052092          
2006-04-04 -1213.508277     
2006-05-04 -1459.290503    
2006-06-04 -1460.119361     
2006-07-04  -772.482609
```

The dataframe has values for every day for a number of years.

I have 2 lists:
yearList - which has the years in the timeseries and looks like:

```
[2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012]
```

monthList - which has the months that are covered in the timeseries and looks like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I would like to (if possible) create a dataframe (indexed by month and year) that sums up the total_cost column.

and would look like:

```
year    month      cost
2006        1     12345
2006        2     12345
:                     :
2012       12     12345
```

the cost in the above output dataframe example is made up

I can see that I  can use (say for November) :

```
df['date'][df['date'].index.month == 11]
```

But how do I add in the year element as well so the pseudo code would look something like for November 2006:

```
df['Dates'][df['Dates'].index.month == 11 && df['date'].index.year== 06]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC.

```
df['Year']=df.index.year
df['Month']=df.index.month
df.groupby(['Year','Month'],as_index=False)['total_cost'].sum()
Out[319]: 
   Year  Month   total_cost
0  2006      3 -1465.052092
1  2006      4 -1213.508277
2  2006      5 -1459.290503
3  2006      6 -1460.119361
4  2006      7  -772.482609
```

Comment: Many thanks, how would I assign the output to a dataframe please?

Comment: @Stacey `df_new=df.groupby(['Year','Month'],as_index=False)['total_cost'].sum()`, you got a new df then

Comment: @Stacey using df.columns=['new','new1','new3']

Comment: thanks, trying      df.columns=['new','new1','new3']
        
    df['new']=performanceData.groupby(['Year','Month'],as_index=False)['total_pnl_pos'].sum()
    df['new1']=performanceData.groupby(['Year','Month'],as_index=False)['total_pnl_pos'].mean()
    df['new3']=performanceData.groupby(['Year','Month'],as_index=False)['total_pnl_pos'].std()    but get error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @Stacey `df['new']=performanceData.groupby(['Year','Month'])['total_pnl_po‌​s'].sum() ` delete the as_index=False

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159784/discussion-between-stacey-and-wen).

Comment: @Stacey sorry I can not using the chat...We can discuss here

Comment: thanks, getting the following error with the code chage:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_unique'

Comment: I'd like to see the output you posted, but in its own dataframe with columns for average and standard deviation as well

Comment: @Stacey `import numpy as np`

`df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['total_co‌​st'].agg([sum,np.mean,np.std])`

Comment: thanks, getting SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier on line: df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['total_co‌​st'].agg([sum,np.mea‌​n,np.std])

Comment: (on the np.std part)

Comment: @Stacey change to ?`df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].agg(['sum','mean','std'])`

Comment: sorry : df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['total_co‌​st'].agg(['sum','mean','std'])
    gives me the error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_unique'

Comment: @Stacey you sure about , the real data you working with is like your sample data ? I run it via your sample data , all good on my side .

Comment: can I upload the file here somehow?